# LINQ-to-XML selection based on node values, newbie question

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML, I would like to return all `eventtitles` where the `eventtype` id = 23. My current query only looks at the first `eventtype`, so returns the wrong result.

```
    <event>
      <eventtitle>Garrison Keillor</eventtitle>
      <eventtypes>
        <eventtype id="24"/>
        <eventtype id="23"/>
      </eventtypes>
    </event>
    <event>
      <eventtitle>Joe Krown Trio featuring Walter Wolfman Washington</eventtitle>
      <eventtypes>
        <eventtype id="23"/>
      </eventtypes>
    </event>
```

LINQ query:

```
Dim query = _
From c In calXML...<event> _
Where c...<eventtypes>.<eventtype>.@id = "23" _
Select c.<eventtitle>.Value, c.<eventlocation>.Value


For Each item In query
    Response.Write("<h3>" & item.eventtitle & "</h3>")
    Response.Write(item.eventlocation & "<br />")
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Any`, like this:

```
Dim query = _ 
From c In calXML...<event> _ 
Where c.<eventtypes>.<eventtype>.Any(Function(t) t.@id = "23") _ 
Select c.<eventtitle>.Value, c.<eventlocation>.Value
```

Comment: What is the significance of the Function?